# AWS S3 sync command doesn't work and no errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can sync data by using this command

```
Aws s3 sync s3://my-source-bucket/2018/11/ s3://my-dest-bucket/2018/11/
```

Then, tried the below command, it's NOT working and NO errors

```
Aws s3 sync s3://my-source-bucket/2021/01/ s3://my-dest-bucket/2021/01/
```

**Any ideas? What are the possible reasons?**

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you saying that no objects were copied? Are there any objects in that source path in S3? (Try `aws s3 ls s3://my-source-bucket/2021/01/` to confirm.) Why is it calling `Aws` instead of `aws`?